# Python, tkinter, window freeze after mainloop (on MacOSX)

Tags: python, bash, tkinter

Could not find anything on this topic in other posts (or maybe I just completely did not understand how tkinter works).

I have a very simple setup where after closing my window, a Shell script is supposed to be executed. The problem (at least on MacOSX) is that while the shell script runs, the window freezes and stays open.

Minimal working example:

```
from tkinter import Tk, Label
from subprocess import call
# GUI
root=Tk()
Label(root,text="Test window").pack()
root.mainloop()
# call
call("sleep 10", shell=True)
# Window stays open and freezes until sleep command returns
```

Am I missing something?

Thanks! Jan

Comment: I cannot reproduce. After closing the window, it disappears and `sleep 10` runs, with the script exiting after `call` completes.

Comment: Thanks, I am wondering if this is an issue specific to my installation.

I am running on MacOSX 10.13.3, Anaconda distribution, Python 3.6.4